# How to resize image in CV2 image in Colab Editor

Tags: python, opencv, resize

I am trying to resize an image in cv2 in Colab editor, but I am getting the below error. Can anyone help me to debug this error?

My code:

```
img= cv2.imread("/content/drive/My Drive/DL_DATAset/Autotag/Test Image/image100.jpg")
height = 220
width = 220
dim = (width, height)
res = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Error:

> error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Comment: This kind of error usually means, that your image (img) is emty. Are yout sure, your image is loaded properly? Maybe you should try to display the image before resizing.

Comment: Do see my answer and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that the image cannot be loaded/read. It's coming from this line here

```
img= cv2.imread("/content/drive/My Drive/DL_DATAset/Autotag/Test Image/image100.jpg")
```

**Path: The image should be in the working directory or a full path of image should be given.**

Are you sure that you are providing that right path to the `imgread()` method? Try giving it a full absolute path, e.g.

```
img= cv2.imread("'C:\Users\User\Desktop\geeksforgeeks.png'")
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can do smth like that

```
docs="""yourstring""".split("\n")

docs

w_corp = 0
w_oracle = 0
w_both = 0
for s in docs:
  s_splited = s.split(" ")
  if "ex1" in s_splited:
    w_corp += 1

  if "ex2" in s_splited:
    w_oracle += 1

  if "ex1" in s_splited and "ex2" in s_splited:
    w_both += 1

import math
max(0, math.log2(len(docs) * w_both / (w_oracle * w_corp)))

import cv2

img = cv2.imread("picture.jpg")

img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

img_shape = img_rgb.shape[:2]

img_shape

k = 3934 / 1967
k

new_h = 5893 / k
new_h

img_resized = cv2.resize(img_rgb, (1967, int(new_h)), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) 
img_resized.shape

k = 3934 / 5893 
k

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a,_,_=plt.hist(img_resized[:, :, 0].ravel(), bins = 256,density=True)
b,_,_=plt.hist(img_resized[:, :, 1].ravel(), bins = 256,density=True)
c,_,_=plt.hist(img_resized[:, :, 2].ravel(), bins = 256,density=True)

max(a.max(), b.max(), c.max())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).